# how to remove the multiple word and corresponding line of file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a text file having fields with delimited by ',' symbol. I want to delete the lines having patters like 'S' and 'A'.

For example, say my file data is like :

```
S,F,T,Y
B,I,J,O
S,O,L,H
R,I,O,P
A,H,K,L
U,I,O,P
A,I,S,U
```

I have tried code for single pattern,Please tell me how to use both patterns in this command:

```
sed -i '/S/d' 'file.txt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command, you should escape the '|' character, which represents the alternation. (A|B, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular expression that will match either A or B)

```
 sed -e '/S\|A/d' file.
```

or

```
 sed -r -e '/S|A/d' file.
```

Comment: It is also working ,I tried with this command,sed -i '/pattern1\|pattern2/d' file.txt

Comment: `sed -n '/S\|A/p' file > delete.txt`

Comment: But it is not deleting from file.txt file.

Comment: @user3829086 Put the `-i` parameter back in.

Comment: Yes, I tried  with sed -i -n '/S\|A/p' file.txt > delete.txt
But,deleted items will be saving in file.txt not in delete.txt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution using `grep` (I'm not very familiar with `sed` unfortunately...):

```
grep -vE 'S|A' input.txt > output.txt
```

It will write in `output.txt` all the lines of `input.txt` which do not contain 'A' or 'S'.

Output:

```
B,I,J,O
R,I,O,P
U,I,O,P
```

Comment: I want to delete it into same file,It should not redirect to other file

Answer (score 0):

@zhujs has the appropriate solution for your example, but for future reference, you can also specify `multiple` commands to `sed` using more than one `-e`

```
sed -e '/A/d' -e '/D/d' file
```